# what does this statics means in Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi currently i'm support a former SF developer in my company. I am pretty new in SF and I found that some of the trigger has this statement from my former SF developer :-->

```
statics.runAppProdTrigger = true;

if(statics.enableContactTrigger){
  ..code here..
}

if(statics.runCampaignMember){
   ..code here..
}
```

may i know what does this statics mean in trigger? how does it works?

Thanks

Comment: Check whether you have initialize a variable called `statics` somewhere above in the trigger. If not check for an Apex class with this name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here statics is likely to be a class name:

```
public class statics {
    public static boolean enableContactTrigger;
    public static boolean runCampaignMember;
    ...
}
```

because a common pattern in triggers is to reference boolean flags defined in a class. Probably not the best class name to choose.

Comment: Yes, i found a class name 'statics'! Thanks! But what is the benefit of having this class? here some code inside this class
"public static Id AccId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'IT-Dept' AND SobjectType = 'Account'].Id;". it just declaring vairables

Comment: @user2074703 One thing it may be doing is allowing logic such as the query to be written once and used in multiple places (code re-use). But also as I mentioned in the answer such a class must be used if you want to set a flag in a trigger that can be referenced in another trigger or another execution of the same trigger - see e.g. http://www.oyecode.com/2012/11/controlling-recursive-triggers-how-to.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here "statics" seems to be an object instance name,  and "runAppProdTrigger" an its boolean property.